# jwtwebtoken expiry reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I am new to Reactjs and would like to know how do we check the token.expiry and log user out when the token has expired?

```
jwt.sign(payload, process.env.jwtSecret, { expiresIn: "60000" });
//for testing purporse, the token is set to be expired after 60000s = 1min 

const isTokenExpired = () => {
    try {
      const decoded = decode(localStorage.getItem("token"));
      if (decoded.exp < (new Date().getTime() + 1) / 1000) {
        return false;
      } else {
        history.push("/");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };
//my code to check whether the token is expired
//when i console.log(decoded.exp, it is a chunk of number, what does it mean?)
```

how do i check every 1 minute on whether my token has expired?

if the token is expired, log the user out; if the token is not expired, continue;

Comment: You need to use setInterval method of Javascript, either in your Redux, Content or any other state management tool you are using.

Comment: Hi, @MubashirEbad! If I set that the token to be expired in 30 mins, would it be possible for me to set interval for every 30 minutes using React Hooks to check whether the token is expired? And where should i place the isTokenExpired method to ensure that it checks on where the user landed?

Comment: Yes you can add a certain interval time in SetInterval method of JavaScript. That depends, if you have a topbar which is there on all pages, you can define it there. If you are using ContextAPIs then you can define a method there as well withint React.useEffect(() => {})

Comment: Hi! I do have an index.js that stores all the routes for the pages! So I will have to place the method here to check every 30 minutes on whether the token has expired, if yes then i remove the token from the localStorage! Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Yeah that is right.

Comment: Thank you, @MubashirEbad!! Your method works like a charm! :) I managed to solve it hehe

Comment: Great, do upvote the answer if it helped you out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add a certain interval time in SetInterval method of JavaScript. That depends, if you have a topbar which is there on all pages, you can define it there. If you are using ContextAPIs then you can define a method there as well withint React.useEffect(() => {}). You can also defined it in the index.js file at the root.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `jwt.verify`, like so:

```
jwt.verify(token, process.env.jwtSecret, function(err, decoded) {
  if (err) {
    //err.name = 'TokenExpiredError, message: jwt expired, expiredAt: <time>
    logout()
  }
}
```

When you `console.log` (decoded.exp) it gives you the the time elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

To check if the user has to be logged out, you could first reset the expires time every time you receive a request. Then after that time has elapsed you could log out the user. Since you verify if the token has expired this should not be necessary. I might be wrong so I welcome comments.

Comment: Hi! Where should i place this method to ensure that this method? is it backend or frontend ?

Comment: Hey, It should be in the backend. Within your server file.